# Apply different font-family to <p> tag according to HTML lang attribute

Tags: html, css

I have two font styles, and i want to apply each different font to `<p>` tag when lang attribute in html changed. For example when lang set to fr change `<p>` `font-family` to fr-font.

Answer (score 5):

You can select your elements with [CSS' attribute selectors](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp). Your code might look like this:

```css
html[lang=fr] p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the lang attribute usually set on the html tag instead of the individual p tags?

Comment: @SwimmerF — Depends on if it is setting the language for the document or the element

Comment: Thankfully, we don't need to worry about mixing attribute selectors and descendant combinators for this any more as we have `:lang`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `:lang` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) which matches an element based on what language it is specified to be (and languages are inherited so you don't need to worry about targetting an element with a specific attribute, descendant combinators, or nesting).

```css
p:lang(en) {
  font-style: italic;
}

p:lang(fr) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div lang="en">
  <p>Is this English?</p>
  <p lang="fr">Est-ce français?</p>
</div>

<div lang="fr">
  <p lang="en">Is this English?</p>
  <p>Est-ce français?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use the `:lang()` attribute in css like this

```css
p:lang(fr) {
  font-family: yourFont;
}
```

Comment: Why are you applying the `:lang` pseudo-class to the HTML element instead of the paragraph? That selects all paragraphs in a primarily French document instead of the French paragraphs.

Comment: @Quentin thats what he wanted to, try reading the question again, he says he want to change the paragraph fonts according to the HTML LANG Attribute

Comment: Given they said `<p>` and HTML and not `<p>` and `<html>` I think we should interpret that mean "The lang attribute defined in the HTML language" and not "on as an attribute of the `<html>` element".

Comment: ahh okay my bad im sorry i didnt notice that haha, i will edit my answer